# Error label executed any time

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba, ms-access-2007

Evening mates!
I have problem with handling error with vba in access. It works fine when error happens, the problem is that the sub is going to execute everything and I always end up with the error message even if I don't have error at all!
the code:

```
Private Sub SaveEmployee_Click()

    On Error GoTo Err_handlar

    If List7.ListCount = 0 Then
     Dim dial As String
     dial = MsgBox("No employee was chosen. Quit the process?", vbYesNo, "No Entry!")
     If dial = vbYes Then
       DoCmd.Close
     End If
    Else
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim record As Recordset
     Dim lname As String
     Dim query As String
     ReDim employeelist(List7.ListCount - 1)
     For i = 0 To List7.ListCount - 1
        lname = Right(List7.ItemData(i), Len(List7.ItemData(i)) - InStrRev(List7.ItemData(i), " "))
        query = "Select EmployeeID from 0TBL_Employees where FirstName =trim('" + Left(List7.ItemData(i), Len(List7.ItemData(i)) - Len(lname)) + " ') and LastName=trim('" + lname + "')"
        Set record = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query)
        employeelist(i) = record!EmployeeID
     Next i
     For i = 0 To 1
       MsgBox employeelist(i)
     Next i
     DoCmd.Close
   End If

 Err_handlar:
    MsgBox "Error during doing the operation, please contact M&E unit!",         vbOKOnly, "Fatal Error"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Exit Sub` line has to be placed *before* Err_handlar: so that normal operation exits before the msgbox.

Comment: Is that how error handler works in vba?
I think jumping in the code would affect the performance.
thanks a lot @pterandon

Comment: I think constantly telling the user there is a fatal error would be a bigger problem with performance.;-)  VBA error handlers live in a labelled section between Exit Sub and End Sub. That way the error handling code is not executed unless an error occurs.